# Installing Composer in Docker container gives Segmentation fault

Tags: docker, composer-php, php-7.1

I am using official php docker image: `7.1-apache`

I am trying to install composer through the docker console and following the steps provided here: https://getcomposer.org/download/

When I get to the third step: `php composer-setup.php`
I get: `Segmentation fault`

I just have no idea what to do. When I was on a lower version of php I had no problems installing composer.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

# Install Xdebug
RUN curl -fsSL 'https://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.4.0.tgz' -o xdebug.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p xdebug \
    && tar -xf xdebug.tar.gz -C xdebug --strip-components=1 \
    && rm xdebug.tar.gz \
    && ( \
    cd xdebug \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure --enable-xdebug \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    ) \
    && rm -r xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Add xdebug cfg
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_log=php7-xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

# Install mcrypt
RUN apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt

# Enable mod_rewrite and ssl
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl

# Restart apache2 to affect changes
RUN service apache2 restart
```

Initially this worked perfectly with php version 7.0. 7.1, however, is not happy with this.

Comment: It works for me. Do you have enough disk space? Any notable errors in system log ?
Maybe try removing and re-pulling the image incase it is corrupted

Comment: Well that's hopeful at least. I think I've left out potentially useful information. I will update with my dockerfile. I only changed the base image then had the problem which is why I thought the rest wasn't relevant. Editing the question now.

Comment: What version of Docker and how is it installed?

Comment: Version: 17.03.0-ce
Installed through the package downloaded on the docker website. I'm using a mac.

Comment: The seg fault has moved... it somehow fixed itself and everything is installed and happy but the moment I try to run a php script it gives segmentation fault. this makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and it was solved when I updated the Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add ca-certificates
```

Then it worked.

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```